# Does mysql support both way replication?

Tags: mysql, database-replication

How can I achieve two way replication in mysql. I know MSSQL supports this. I need to write on both side and it should propagate accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a reference:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html

Though its for one way. But after setting up one way replication, you can set in reverse order, i.e. former slave will be master and former master will be slave.

For reverse case, you need to run these only:

in master (former slave)

mysql>`GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'user'@'host' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`
mysql>`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

in slave (former master)
$ `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

mysql>

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='master_host',
        MASTER_USER='user',
         MASTER_PASSWORD='password';
```

mysql> `START SLAVE;`

in new master

mysql> `SHOW MASTER STATUS;`

Answer (score 0):

Both way replication is called Mirroring:

https://www.ryadel.com/en/mysql-master-master-replication-setup-in-5-easy-steps/

Comment: Although the link provided may answer the question, there is no guarantee of it being up in the future. to avoid this, always consider adding the main / key points of the link in your answer and provide the link as the source / reference instead.